# What punctuation do I use in "Всё, что ... это ..." constructs?

Tags: пунктуация

In the following sentence, do I need a comma before "это"? Or a dash? Or just a space would be all right?

> Всё, что им нужно было **сделать, это** просто спеть эту песню.

or

> Всё, что им нужно было **сделать - это** просто спеть эту песню.

or

> Всё, что им нужно было **сделать это** просто спеть эту песню.
>   ?

Comment: My guess is variant 1 or variant 4 (`Всё, что им нужно было сделать, — это просто спеть эту песню.`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one. When a comma and a dash have to be used in the same place, the comma usually replaces the dash.

UPD sorry, my bad. A comma here would be colloquial. It's so widely used that I didn't even detect it as a mistake, shame on me ^_^

Смещение конструкции может найти свое выражена в том, что главное предложение «перебивается» находящимся внутри его придаточным, например:
«Последнее, на чем следует остановиться, это на композиции книги» (следует: Последнее, на чем следует остановиться – это композиция книги).

Розенталь Д.Э., Джанджакова Е.В., Кабанова Н.П.

СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ

Comment: So, do the comma and the dash need to be together or should the comma replace the dash here?

Comment: @brilliant The comma replaces the dash. The only cases where a comma and a dash go together are here: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm#з_07 and in direct speech.

Comment: @brilliant Oops, my bad. See edit ^^"

Answer (score 0):

> Всё, что им нужно было сделать - это просто спеть эту песню.

This is a correct variant.

Comment: Please, cite some sources.

Comment: @brilliant, I am a russian guy :(

Comment: I am Russian, too. However, it doesn't change the need in providing sources in the answer :)

Comment: @brilliant, okay, I got it. In next time I will try to give some sourse.

Comment: @Denis I look things up in Rozental to prove that I'm right (or wrong in this case) :) One simple site-restricted google search, and it's all there ;)

Comment: @Kaworu - "One simple site-restricted google search" - Why do you mean by "site-restricted search?

Comment: @brilliant Erm... Site-specific? Like "site:evartist.narod.ru".